# Select webapp start up page based on domain name

Tags: java, tomcat7

How to select a start up page of tomcat 7 webapp?

There is mainly two page in my webapp and I want to select based on domain name. for example

if admin.foo.com show admin.jsp

if user.foo.com show user.jsp

and if foo.com show index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

You have to build this logic into a filter or a servlet in your webapplication. Basically, what you would do is to use [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) to parse out the subomain of the request, and then redirect your visitor to the appropriate page.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a redirection-servlet, and use [HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) to distinguish between the URLs requested by the user and redirect based on that.

When the user accesses the servlet, respond with the appropriate .jsp-file based on the domain used.